# js html recieving text from file and posting in form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, reader

I have recently been experimenting with file-to-text programs, and I have came across a minor problem.  The web browser received the text file I had originally wanted, but it placed the text in the div container rather than in the input box as I originally wanted.  Can anyone help?

This program is the base of a larger program.  I have multiple applications which do not allow the use of the copy/paste function for security reasons, specifically accountant programs.  So I am forced to manually copy over the data I already have in separate file into the program.

My goal in this base program is to receive data from a text file, and then automatically place it into a form input(which I coded to deny any paste function to simulate the other program).

Here is the source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.onpaste = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
}

var openFile = function(event) {
var input = event.target;

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
var text = reader.result;
var node = document.getElementById('output');
node.innerText = text;
console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
};
reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<div id='output'>
...

<input type="text" value="" id='myInput' />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```